# Problem when installing Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, mysql, dependencies

I tried to install MSSQL-Server using Microsoft's guide but I get this error during the installation, I tried Synaptic but it did not work, I browsed trough Stackexchange running some terminal codes but it did not help either, here is the error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And here is the other error when I try to update:

```
dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--configure):
 installed msodbcsql17 package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mssql-tools:
 mssql-tools depends on msodbcsql17 (>= 17.3.0.0); however:
  Package msodbcsql17 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mssql-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
 mssql-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I apologize if its too long.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install SQL Server onto? 20.04 or 22.04? 

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 broke compatibility. Libldap is no longer in apt or snap, you have to find it somewhere else. I run 22.04 and have th

Comment: ... looks like you need to [edit] and complete your thought

Comment: Can you tell me how did you install on Ubuntu 22?